Different keyboard combination for switching a certain language
on my system I have 3 languages for my keyabord and they can be switched by pressing shift+alt combination, but it's not always convenient to switch between 3 languages, especially while programming so I'd like to know, is there a way to leave 2 languages switching pressing shift+alt, but the other language will use different combination to be switched, so that pressing shift+alt I won't switch on it, but only a different combination?
